# Non app store apps for iPhone 3G

Tags: ios-appstore, iphone

I recently bought iPhone 3G from a friend, but i can't download apps from the official appstore because my iOS version is 4.2. Is there any website or even a way to install apps like facebook, without custom firmware like whited00r?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. If an app requires a certain version of iOS, then you must meet that requirement, otherwise the app will not be able to be installed. You may be able to get hold of a version of the app that used to work on iOS 4.2, but it depends on the app.

Comment: Yes but iTunes has an option for installing apps, what if i find file.app to install?

Comment: @All Yes, if you get an ipa for an older version of the app, then you will be able to install the app through iTunes.

Comment: Does my device need to be jailbroken or i can install any ipa?